# Three.js - low performance on only 40 "simple" models

Tags: javascript, three.js

[Here's a test field.](http://creation.pl/model_test) Just click on model1-model4 to add next model. Remember to move camera (by mouse) to see real FPS.

I got few simple models... no matter if I use reflection or not, or I smooth vertices or not, when got about 40 models drawn, got only about 20-25 fps (while moving scene!)... 55 models = about 12 fps! any idea why? Graphic card or computer doesn't really matter... tested on Quad Core 4x3.6Ghz, 8GB ram, Geforce 880GTX. But Xperia Z1 acts similar.

Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to make it better? For example Ogre can render up to 5000 exactly the same models without a choke (DirectX).

Comment: Are you running in Chrome or Firefox? In your example the check-boxes don't work for me. Even if I uncheck reflection, I still get reflection on the objects. Same with smoothness. Dont see any difference.

Comment: Checkboxes only work when creating new object. It does not modify existing ones. Tested on Chrome, FireFox, Opera... about the same results. Model 4 shows exactly that not much of polygons were used on those models (leave reflex, don't smooth).

Comment: Type `renderer.info` into the console. Do some experiments to see if textures or geometries are the problem. Update to r.67 please. Unrelated: There is no need to call `camera.lookAt()`, since you are using a Control.

Comment: It is r.67... what do I need `renderer.info` for? this is weird that without smoothing vertices there are more vertives than with smoothing them... but still have no idea how to fix fps... I need to display about 2000 of models...

Comment: Did you do any experiments yet as I suggested?

Comment: Probably it is not the real issue, but: 1) In the uniforms, there is the refraction index. I don't think it's needed. 2) I don't know why, but taking a snapshot gives 2 separate full renders.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading a new obj everytime you should do obj.clone() if you have loaded it already. That way you'll be reusing geometries and textures.

I notice you're trying to have a cubemap, but your textures are not power of 2 (432x432). Try resizing them to 256x256 or 512x512.